# Cannot click on selected Item when the value is null primefaces

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I have a selectOneMenu, in my xhtml page, when i want to click in a selectItem with the itemValue is null, there is no effect, it shows the default selection

```
 <p:selectOneMenu id="cout" style="width: 120px;" value="#{serviceManagedBean.selectedService.coutSmsCalc}">
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez une" itemValue="" />
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="oui" itemValue="oui" />  
                      <f:selectItem itemLabel="non" itemValue="" />
                    </p:selectOneMenu>
```

So, when i click in the itemLabel "non", it remains on "Sélectionnez une"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this if the item value is a String

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez une" itemValue="{null}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="oui" itemValue="oui" />  
<f:selectItem itemLabel="non" itemValue="non" />
```

Or try this if the item value is boolean

```
<f:selectItem itemLabel="Sélectionnez une" itemValue="{null}" />
<f:selectItem itemLabel="oui" itemValue="true" />  
<f:selectItem itemLabel="non" itemValue="false" />
```

Answer (score 1):

The selectOneMenu use itemValue to change the displayed value. So if your value is null like the default one, the action changeListener is not called. Try to change the itemValue by empty or other key.